# How to get Json operators in PSQL/HSQL working?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I am trying to utilize the '->' operator in a query binded by the PanacheEntityBase class's 'find' function but am getting errors saying that the query does not recognize the '>' character. This is to extract a column value of jsonb.

The same query works fine when working in a query console, so I am assuming this has to do with the type of SQL that is used being different between the function and the console.

Is there a function equivalent to the '->' operator? I've found one for the '#>' but that does not seem to do the trick.

Comment: So the equivalent is jsonb_object_field but now I'm getting an error saying there is no data type for node...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66422438/getting-java-lang-illegalstateexception-no-data-type-for-node-org-hibernate-hq this has helped